# Minimizing computational time for a quantum walk problem

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, sparse-arrays, quantum-computing

Any suggestions as to how to speed up the computational time for this quantum walk problem which is coded using a normalized SparseArray coin operator as follows:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(*Define number of sites*)
n = 10;

init = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1, {i_, 1} /; i != 1 -> 0}, {n, 1}];
init = Normalize[init, Norm[#, 1] &];

(*Coin operator*)
Hadamardg = 
  SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; i == j -> 
     1/Sqrt[2], {i_, j_} /; j == i + 1 || j == i - 1 -> 
     1/Sqrt[2]}, {n, n}];
Hadamardg = MatrixPower[Hadamardg, 1/2];
Hadamardg = Normalize[Hadamardg, Norm[#, 1] &];

Shift = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 0, {i_, j_} /; j == i + 1 -> 
     1, {i_, j_} /; j == i - 1 -> 1}, {n, n}];

steps = 5;

(* Quantum walk *)
state = Nest[(Shift . Hadamardg . #) &, init, steps];

ListPlot[Transpose[Abs[state]^2][[1]], PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Position", "Probability"}]
```

Comment: Use numeric computation instead of symbolic in `MatrixPower` as `Hadamardg = MatrixPower[Hadamardg // N, 1/2];`

Comment: Also dotting `A = Shift . Hadamardg` only once and then doing `state = Nest[(A.#) &, init, steps];` might pay off.

Comment: These comments are useful for sure, trying to amend the code so that the output is normalized and does not yield large values if number of sites or steps are inccreased

Comment: Moreover, for small `n` and large `steps`, you might want to consider also to diagonalize `A`. Then each iteration (i.e., multiplying with the diagonal) costs `n` instead of `n^2`. Diagonalization costs `O(n^3)`, so this should be faster only if `steps * n^2` is much greater than `n^3 + steps * n` .

Comment: And apparently, you are only interested in the final state. This can be obtained from `MatrixPower[A, steps, Flatten[init]]`, of course.

Comment: Btw. I don't know much about quantum something something; I too only the first class is quantum mechanics. But since you interpret the squared modulus of `state`: shouldn't it be `init = Normalize[init, Norm[#, 2] &];` (or `init = Normalize[init]`, which is shorter), and shoudn't the matriz you apply recursively be _unitrary_? Like $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \,\Delta t \, H}$? with a self-adjoint matrix `H`?

Comment: if this is a standard 1D QW, only either even or odd sites are occupied at each step. You can therefore reduce by half the dimension of the effective space needed to describe the evolution: it's sufficient to have an $(n+1)$-dimensional walker space after $n$ steps, having the c-shift either move right or not move at all (as opposed to either move right or move left). The physics you get is identical, up to trivial relabelling

Answer (score 4):

With inclusion of changes based on earlier comments, and Normalization of state, and few changes, rapid computational time is noted. The amended code is as follows:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

(* No. of sites*)
n = 30;

(* Initial state*)
init = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1, {i_, 1} /; i != 1 -> 0}, {n, 1}];
init = Normalize[init, Norm[#, 2] &];

(* Coin operator*)
Hadamardg = 
  SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; i == j -> 
     1/Sqrt[2], {i_, j_} /; j == i + 1 || j == i - 1 -> 
     1/Sqrt[2]}, {n, n}];
Hadamardg = MatrixPower[Hadamardg // N, 1/2];
Hadamardg = Normalize[Hadamardg, Norm[#, 2] &];

(* Shift operator*)
Shift = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 0, {i_, j_} /; j == i + 1 -> 
     1, {i_, j_} /; j == i - 1 -> 1}, {n, n}];

(* No. of steps*)
steps = 30;

(* Quantum walk & store probability distribution for each 
step*)
Aqw = Shift . Hadamardg;
state = init;
probDist = {};
Do[state = Normalize[Aqw . state, Norm[#, 2] &];
  AppendTo[probDist, Transpose[Abs[state]^2][[1]]];, {i, 1, steps}];

(*Plot probability distribution for each step in a 3D plot*)
probDist3D = 
 ListPlot3D[probDist, DataRange -> {{1, steps}, {1, n}}, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Steps", "Position", "Probability"}]
```

[image]

Comment: `NestList` would be much better than `AppendTo` here.